# Wifi keeps slowing down or refusing to work

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, connection

I have my dell latitude e7240 laptop on which I currently run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I had to reinstall it yesterday because I kind of nuked my /user directory by accident. When it came to it I also chose to encrypt the whole disk. The installation proceeded without anything unusual.

When then trying to download anything (like openJDK-14, InteliJ, anything that requires a bit more than few MBs to download) the wifi would start dropping from 400~Mbs all the way down to nothing. The wifi icon would then just display empty icon with question mark in it, no connection to anywhere. The only way of getting it to work again is to reset it either by turning it on and of or using the wifi kill switch.

I tried searching for this issue but only found something few years back that was related to the wifi chipset being to new or something like that.

I don't really know what to do since everything worked just fine before the reinstall.

Comment: It sounds like a WiFi driver issue. My guess us you have a realtek WiFi device and the wrong driver has been detected. What is the output of "lspci" ?

Comment: @davidgo can't paste the whole thing but the network controller line is `02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)`